# White Rock WP theme and WooCommerce compatibility issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

UPDATED

This is a question that is specific to a couple if items, so please ask for more detail if need be and I will do my best to provide it.

The issue:
I am using a WordPress theme called "White Rock" (http://themeforest.net/item/white-rock-restaurant-winery-theme/3317744).  This theme does not have built in compatibility with WooCommerce.  However, I have managed to get 99% of things working with some code changes and other plugins.  When you browse to a single product page (https://www.parisisrestaurant.com/wptest/product/1048/) there is no header image being displayed, as there is at: https://www.parisisrestaurant.com/wptest/shop/store/

The theme uses the pages "featured image" to append the image in the header of the page.  However, since the first link I provided you is not a "page" but rather, a product, it does not function in the same manner.  I believe WooCommerce uses the standard page.php within my template to render the product pages.  This code consists of:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package progression
 * @since progression 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?> 

    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'progression' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>      

<?php if(of_get_option('page_comments_default', '0')): ?><?php comments_template( '', true ); ?><?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

A product in WooCommerce does not have a "featured image" but rather a "product image" which I assume is about the same thing.  In any case, I can not get the header image to display at the top of the page.

Does anyone have an idea of how I might fix this?  If additional code or clarification is needed, please let me know.  This issue has been driving me nuts all week!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATED:

I have found that the single product pages in woocommerce are using the following template (woocommerce/templates/single-product.php):

```
    <?php
    /**
     * The Template for displaying all single products.
     *
     * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php
     *
     * @author      WooThemes
     * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
     * @version     1.6.4
     */

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

    get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
             * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
        ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
        ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_sidebar hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
        ?>

    <?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

On top of this, the header image display is being called from (White Rock: page-title-progression.php):

```
<?php if(is_404() ): ?>
    <div id="page-title">
        <div class="width-container paged-title">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( '404 Page Not Found ', 'progression' ); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
    </div><!-- #page-title -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
            $("#page-title").backstretch([
                "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                    if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                        echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                    }

                    if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                        echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            ],{
                    fade: 750,
                    duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
             });
        });

        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>

    <?php if(is_page()): ?>
        <?php
        global $wp_query;
        $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
        ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_home() || is_single() && 'portfolio' != get_post_type() && 'menu' != get_post_type() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo get_the_title($page_for_posts); ?></h1>
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_archive() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'F Y' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ( is_tag() ) : ?>
                        <?php
                            printf( __( 'Tag: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . single_tag_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ( is_author() ) : ?>
                        <?php _e( 'Author Archives:', 'progression' ); ?>
                        <?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
                              echo '' . $user_info->display_name . "\n";
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if(post_type_exists('menu') ) : ?>
                        <?php
                            printf( __( '%s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_search() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search for: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1></div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>

        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_single() && 'portfolio' == get_post_type() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if(is_single() && 'menu' == get_post_type() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this sheds a bit more light on the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The header image isn't appearing because the following div isn't appearing in the product pages:

```
<div class="backstretch" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 248px; width: 1351px; z-index: -999998; position: absolute;">
    <img src="https://www.parisisrestaurant.com/wptest/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/DSC_0655-1600x300.jpg" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 1351px; height: 253.3125px; max-width: none; z-index: -999999; top: -2.65625px; left: 0px;">
</div>
```

That div is found in the `page-title` div just under the `<header>` tag.

Comment: Right, so the problem exists of how to add the proper code to the proper php file.  I believe I need to copy the image header part (code) from the white rock theme into the woocommerce product page template (woocommerce/templates/single-product.php).  However, I am not sure where to find the proper code to copy.  I am only guessing at this point.

Comment: I have updated the post with new information I obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to create a new if statement for product pages:  `<?php if(is_product()): ?>` within the page-title-progression.php file